# How do you set the text colour in Indesign to change depending on page background?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, text

I have an InDesign spread where some pages have a white background and some have a red background.

[image]

I want to flow text across both types of pages, and change the text colour depending on what the background is.

I could change it manually, but obviously then when I change the text / resize text boxes there is a good chance I'll end up with the wrong colour text on the page. Is there a way I can set this?

Have seen people do something using blending modes, but that's not really going to work here. I want white text on the red background pages and grey text on the white background pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text should only be white you could use the *effects-panel*. 
select the textframe you want to have white, go to effects and change the **transparency** of the **text** to *negative multiplication*. If you want to have the inverted color you could also use *difference* (but it's not that readable).

I'm afraid, I couldn't find a way to give it a specific color but if white is enough that should be a way to do it. It will work with resizing the frames, I tested it.

[image]

Comment: I think this blending mode is called 'Screen' in English. Awesome option, I never even knew of the existence of this panel. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Create master pages with the different color backgrounds that you can easily drag into place. And create paragraph or character styles for the different text colors.

Answer (score -1):

Under Effects. Go to transparacent
Select Color Dodge